# setFont slows down the execution of the program

Tags: java, fonts, awt

i have this class,on which i noticed if i use `setFont(...)` it 'll slow down the execution of the entire program.

```
public class MenuState extends GameState {

private String[] options = { "Start ", "Options","Quit"};
private int currentSelection;
private Font font;

protected MenuState(GameStateManager gameStateManager) {
    super(gameStateManager);
    init();
}

public void init() {
    currentSelection = 0;
    font = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 30);
}

public void update() {

}

public void render(Graphics graphic) {
    for (int i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        if (i == currentSelection) {
            graphic.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        } else {
            graphic.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
        if (i == 0) {
            graphic.setFont(font);
            graphic.drawString(options[i],
                    GuiDimension.WIDTH.getValue() / 2 - 47, 500);
        }
        if (i == 1) {
            graphic.setFont(font);
            graphic.drawString(options[i],
                    GuiDimension.WIDTH.getValue() / 2 - 107, 550);
        }
        if (i == 2) {
            graphic.setFont(font);
            graphic.drawString(options[i],
                    GuiDimension.WIDTH.getValue() / 2 - 47, 600);
        }

    }

}
```

now if if I comment this row:

- `graphic.setFont(font);`

the execution is normal otherwise it is slow.

someone can tell me the reason?

Comment: Don't know -- but do you need to call `setFont()` three times?  Why not move it up out of your for loop and call it only once?

Comment: it was that! thanks, i didn't think about it.